# Why is Win 7 IE removing "all-permissions" tag from JNLP after download for Java Webstart?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

We recently deployed a JavaFX app that uses Webstart.  The app has “all-permissions” in the Jar Manifest, and "all-permissions" in the JNLP.   The Jar files are signed with a Comodo code-signing certificate.

End-users visit an HTML page which has a button they click that downloads the JNLP file.

The app launches okay on all systems except for when using IE 11 on Windows 7.  They receive the following pop-up error (note, on the same Windows 7 machine with Chrome/Firefox, the app launches okay...and I have made sure all Java options are the same across all machines):

[image: Java pop-up error]

The JNLP file on the server is below, with all-permissions tag set:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="SXScheduler-1.jnlp">
  <information> 
    <title>SX Scheduler</title>
    <vendor>SX</vendor>
    <description>SX Scheduler</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security> 
    <all-permissions/> 
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="SXScheduler-1-jfx.jar" size="778804" download="null" />
    <jar href="lib/activation-1.1.1.jar" size="69409" download="null" />
    …more lib/ jar files, removed for Stack Overflow brevity
  </resources>
  <jfx:javafx-desc width="800" height="600" main-class="main.App" name="SXScheduler-1" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
```

My conclusion for the failure is because the “all-permissions” is being removed in the JNLP file after it is downloaded in IE on Windows 7.

Why is it being removed?

Here are snippets from the Java console on fail (on the systems that work, the JNLP file in the console has the “all-permissions” tag):

```
Java Plug-in 11.161.2.12 x86
Using JRE version 1.8.0_161-b12 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Jones
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
network: Created version ID: 1.5.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.161
network: Created version ID: 1.8
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.161
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@29614cd5: 5
basic: XMLParser with _source:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="SXScheduler-1.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>SX Scheduler</title>
    <vendor>SX</vendor>
    <description>SX Scheduler</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="SXScheduler-1-jfx.jar" size="778804" download="null" />
    <jar href="lib/activation-1.1.1.jar" size="69409" download="null" />
…more lib/ jar files, removed for Stack Overflow brevity
  </resources>
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="main.App"  name="SXScheduler-1" />
  <update check="background"/>
</jnlp>
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():
 
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="http://pmmsoft.com/deploy10/" href=“http://removed_for_privacy/deploy10/SXScheduler-1.jnlp”>
  <information>
    <title>SX Scheduler</title>
    <vendor>SX</vendor>
    <homepage href="null"/>
    <description>SX Scheduler</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <update check="background" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <java href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" version="1.7+"/>
    <jar href=“htttp://removed for privacy/deploy10/SXScheduler-1-jfx.jar” download="eager" main="false"/>
   <jar href="http://removed for privacy/deploy10/lib/activation-1.1.1.jar" download="eager" main="false"/>
  …more lib/ jar files, removed for Stack Overflow brevity
  </resources>
  <javafx-desc main-class="main.App"/>
</jnlp>
...more output (irrelevant) removed for Stack Overflow brevity
 java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest requested to run in all-permissions only: http://removed for privacy/deploy10/SXScheduler-1-jfx.jar
                   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployManifestChecker.verify(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.deploy.security.SandboxSecurity.isPermissionGranted(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.performSecurityCheckForSandbox(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
                   at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
                   at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
                   at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
                   at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    basic: The Java security settings have prevented this application from running. You may change this behavior in the Java Control Panel.
```

Thank you everyone for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Have you considered doing what it says in the popup?

Comment: The app loads on Chrome and Firefox on the same Windows 7 machines that fail with IE.  I have made sure Java control panel options are the same across all machines.

Comment: Have a look at chapter 7.2 and following https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/plugin.html

Comment: There is nothing here that suggests that the culprit is Win 7 IE. It can only be the Java installation.

Comment: EJP - This has been tested on numerous Win 7 laptops and desktops, at different businesses and personal computers, and with IE, they all fail as I described ("all-permissions" removed).  And on all those computers, they all launch the app perfectly with Chrome and/or Firefox.